# Getting Page<T> page object from List<T> list object

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data

I have a specific list of entities. My model resieves as an attribute `Page<T> page` object, bacause I have a pagination. Is there any way to "convert" `List<T> list` to `Page<T> page`, taking into consideration the arrguments that I want to use: `int page, int size`?

My controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/symptoms", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String symptomPage(
        @RequestParam(required = false, value = "rows") Integer rows,
        @RequestParam(required = false, value = "page") Integer tabNumber,
        @RequestParam(required = false, value = "sort") String order,
        @RequestParam(required = false, value = "isSorted") Boolean isSorted,
        @RequestParam(required = false, value = "search") String search,
        Model model) {
    Page<Symptom> page = null;
    if (rows == null && tabNumber == null) {
        page = symptomService.findSymptomsPages(0, 10);
    }
    else if(!isSorted){
        page = symptomService.findSymptomsPages(tabNumber - 1, rows, search);
    } else {
        page = symptomService.findSortedSymptomPages(tabNumber - 1, rows, order, search);
    }
    int currentPage = page.getNumber() + 1;
    int first = Math.max(1, currentPage - 3);
    int last = Math.min(currentPage + 3, page.getTotalPages());

    model.addAttribute("symptom", new Symptom());
    model.addAttribute("symptomPage", page);
    model.addAttribute("currentPage", currentPage);
    model.addAttribute("first", first);
    model.addAttribute("last", last);
    return "symptoms";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Define the range from the list you want to use for the page. And take required sub-list:

```
class Page<T> {
    private final List<T> list;
    private final pageSize;

    // ... consturcotor

    int getTabCount() {
        return (list.size() + pageSize - 1) / pageSize;
    }

    List<T> getTabContent(int tab) {
        int fromIndex = tab * size;
        int toIndex = (tab + 1) * size;
        if (fromIndex < 0)
            fromIndex = 0;
        if (toIndex > list.size())
            toIndex = list.size();
        if (fromIndex > toIndex)
            toIndex = fromIndex;
        return list.subList(fromIndex, toIndex);
    }
}
```

Comment: In that case my pagination has only 1 tab, no matter of what list size is.

Comment: you really don't understand original hint, do you? or it was a joke?